# Bulb turn signals with all other lights LED?

Tags: tail-lights, led

I've noticed on some newer cars (sorry, no specific examples), that they often have LED brake lights, but still use an incandescent amber bulb for the turn signals.  Is there a reason that a manufacturer doesn't just convert everything to LED and not have any incandescent bulbs on the vehicle at all (except maybe headlights)?

Comment: My new car is like this...  Cool LED tail lights and running lights, but rear brake lights and all turn signals are incandescent.  Not sure if you'll get anything other than informed opinion answers, but I wondered the same thing.

Comment: This will vary between the manufacturers. Some are all LED and some aren't. Could be cost related or not. Only the OEMs can say for sure. I have noticed some of the LED turn signal lights appear to flash faster than the standard bulbs.